# Using ffmpeg to generate RTSP from webcam

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I want to get the camera video stream and broadcast it with RTSP on Windows.

I can play the camera video with

```
> ffplay -f dshow -i "HP HD Webcam"
```

But if I try start the stream with

```
> ffmpeg -f rtsp -i video="HP HD Webcam" rtsp://localhost:8888/live.sdp
```

The stream does not start. The console shows

```
ffmpeg version ...
configuration: ...
libavutil      55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
libavcodec     57. 15.100 / 57. 15.100
libavformat    57. 14.100 / 57. 14.100
libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
libavfilter     6. 15.100 /  6. 15.100
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
```

And if I use ctrl+c to break it, an error shows

```
video=HP HD Webcam: Immediate exit requested
```

How can I properly stream the camera to RTSP with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ffmpeg` doesn't substitute a RTSP server, the `rtsp` is just a muxer/demuxer. When you use it for output it sends the stream with a `RTSP ANNOUNCE`. So you need a server which supports it running on 8888. The [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp) mentions [Darwin Streaming Server](http://dss.macosforge.org/) and [revmischa/rtsp-server](https://github.com/revmischa/rtsp-server).

Answer (score 10):

First, you have to create an RTSP server, then Push Video stream from Webcam to RTSP server. once server is up, Read the Stream from RTSP server.
Follow the steps below in ***Ubuntu***:

Open Terminal and execute following

```
$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
$ sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```

**Step 1:** Open a new terminal and
Download SimpleRTSP server package:

```
 $ wget https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server/releases/download/v0.16.0/rtsp-simple-server_v0.16.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz
```

Extract downloaded package:

```
$ tar -xzvf rtsp-simple-server_v0.16.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz
```

**Step 2:** Check for your internal [IP address](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430853/how-do-i-find-my-internal-ip-address) with following command:

```
$ ifconfig
```

*Copy an IP* address eg. 192.168.XXX.XXX

**Step 3:** Now, Start RTSP Server

```
$ rtspServer=192.168.XXX.XXX:rtsp://192.168.XXX.XXX:8554/webCamStream ./rtsp-simple-server
```

(Add your IP address in the above command)

**Step 4:** Open a new terminal

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

(Ensure you have a webcam plugged in and installed > sudo apt-get install v4l-utils)
This will give a list of all the camera devices plugged into your system
eg.

```
UVC Camera (046d:0825) (usb-0000:00:14.0-1):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

**Step 5:** You can now, push video stream from webcam to RTSP server:

```
$ sudo ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 24 -video_size 480x480 -i /dev/video0 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://192.168.XXX.XXX:8554/webCamStream
```

(add your IP address, port, and stream name in the above command)

**Step 6:** Last step is to check and view your RTSP feed:
open a new terminal and check with the following command

```
$ ffplay "rtsp://192.168.XXX.XXX:8554/webCamStream"
```

Comment: I found [mediamtx](https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx/releases) to be a very good alternative to `rtsp-simple-server`, extremely easy to use.